# Rails form text field helper, how to make the input area wider?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I make the text field area wider?

I tried:

f.text_field   :title, size => 150

I also tried width, I am missing something here, what is it?

Answer (score 19):

I think it should be

```
f.text_field :title, :size => 150
```

Or, you can add :class option and use css to define the size (I prefer)

Answer (score 16):

You can also do something like:

```
    <%= f.text_area :description, :cols => "10", :rows => "10" %>
```

Comment: This answer set the text input area to the desired shape/geometry. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the same in your code. I think you are missing a colon before the size.

> <%= f.text_field :title, :size => 150
>   %>

or you can use

> <%= f.text_field :title, "size" => 150
>   %>

**size is an undefined local variable** whereas **:size and "size"** are passed as options to the text field form helper

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by simply using **rows option** in your text field. Like

```
<%= f.text_area :fieldname, :rows => "10" %>
```

Comment: Works nicely! Notice that it's "f.text_area" rather than "f.text_field". (I didn't noticed that from the beginning)

Answer (score 0):

Size should work, could you post a chunk of code?

[FormHelper Documentation](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M000445)

Answer (score 0):

You can always specify a class using the class symbol and specify a width using CSS

`<%=text_field_tag 'some_input', nil, :class => 'some-class'%>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the input field

```
<%= f.input :content, as: :text, input_html: { rows: "2" } %>
```